# Does Integer.parseInt(String) creates object?

Tags: java, android

I am using `int duration = Integer.parseInt(durationInString)` to convert String object to primitive integer value. I am using this in a while loop and the integer conversion happens every second until the end of video duration. For example - if Video is 2 min I will call `Integer.parseInt` 120 times. 
I wanted to know if every call to `Integer.parseInt` creates a object? If so is it a bad idea to have it called continuously?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Note: I am working on Android application

Thanks,
SKU

Comment: is there a reason you have to call this every second? I'm guessing the video duration doesn't change, wouldn't it be enough to only call it once? If there's no good reason, then yes, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Once every second is not very often. The garbage collector can cope up with that easily.

Comment: @ggreiner The reason I am calling it for every second is to get the current position of the video play. By getting the return value... I will set the progress bar's position to update the view.

Comment: @Guillaume I kinda felt the same, more over I am doing this on a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally the method might create objects, but since the return value is an `int` it is not producing any objects that leak out to you, the caller.  I would not worry about the efficiency concerns of object creation like this, since most JVMs have garbage collectors that are specifically optimized to collect young objects that are no longer referenced.  If you have reason to believe that this method is creating objects at a rate that actually causes a problem, then pull out a profiler to inspect it.  I would wager that it is not a bottleneck.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the source code for Integer.parseInt, no objects seem to be created.

That said, 120 times isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: Though, in fairness, the library designer is free to implement this method as they see fit and could indeed allocate objects internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the code from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410611/678189

Anyway, I think is better having:

```
int duration = 0;
while(){
duration = whatever;
}
```

So that memory can be reused.