# typecasting internal process in java

Tags: java

When i use

```
   String s = "12";      
   int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

This is giving `n` value as 12 .That is fine for me.

What it is doing internally. What is the internal process here
running. Can some one explain? How a string really converting as a
integer. Before giving any downvote please give me the reason. I will rectify
my mistake next time. I searched for this question. But i did not
find answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410555/how-does-integer-parseintstring-actually-work

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410555/how-does-integer-parseintstring-actually-work

Comment: You are calling the static method "parseInt".  You are not "typecasting" anything.

Comment: Did you see the source of Integer.parseInt?http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.parseInt%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29

Comment: It simply gets the string char by char and then convert it to int. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is the actual implementation of parseInt method please go through ::

```
    public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
         return parseInt(s,10);
    }

    public static int parseInt(String s, int radix) throws NumberFormatException
    {
        if (s == null) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("null");
        }

    if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + radix +
                        " less than Character.MIN_RADIX");
    }

    if (radix > Character.MAX_RADIX) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + radix +
                        " greater than Character.MAX_RADIX");
    }

    int result = 0;
    boolean negative = false;
    int i = 0, max = s.length();
    int limit;
    int multmin;
    int digit;

    if (max > 0) {
        if (s.charAt(0) == '-') {
        negative = true;
        limit = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        i++;
        } else {
        limit = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        multmin = limit / radix;
        if (i < max) {
        digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
        if (digit < 0) {
            throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
        } else {
            result = -digit;
        }
        }
        while (i < max) {
        // Accumulating negatively avoids surprises near MAX_VALUE
        digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
        if (digit < 0) {
            throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
        }
        if (result < multmin) {
            throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
        }
        result *= radix;
        if (result < limit + digit) {
            throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
        }
        result -= digit;
        }
    } else {
        throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
    }
    if (negative) {
        if (i > 1) {
        return result;
        } else {    /* Only got "-" */
        throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
        }
    } else {
        return -result;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why it is down. This is the actual implementation of parseInt method which demonstrate how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Peek inside the internal code of `Integer.parseInt()`, for example [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html) at line 444.

But the easiest way if you attach the `src.zip` from your Java installation into your favorite editor (e.g. Eclipse) as a source the `Integer.class` - this way you will get the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

in this post : [how it's working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410555/how-does-integer-parseintstring-actually-work)
 it is nicely shown, how it's working. You should be able to understand it properly after reading

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to attach the source codes to the IDE you like and when you need something you will only need to jump into the source code of any library. 
Best way to do it is to use IntelliJ IDEA and create empty Maven module. Then after jumping into the method implementation you will be asked to download the sources... Fast and easy.